# How can I auto increment variable names in for loop?

Tags: java, android, xml

**API Level:** 12 (Android 3.1)

**App Background:** Through my Android app I am sending a request to our web servers MySQL database to retrieve companies. All of that works fine. Originally I had the returned data populate a `ListView`, but to get the visual my boss prefers I have 6 `TextView`'s evenly distributed. (This app is designed to only work on ONE device, the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1)

**Question:** So, in parsing the returned data I have a `for` loop. What I would like to do, is auto increment a variable i.e. `company_ + i` then `i++`. Is this possible in Java or is there a better way?

Here is an example of how I would think it would work:

```
int length = 5;

//parse JSON data
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++){

        TextView company = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.company_ + i);

        JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String businessName = jObject.getString("businessName");
            double distance = jObject.getDouble("distance");

            double distRound = 1e5;
            double roDistance = Math.round(distance * distRound) / distRound;

            company.setText(businessName);
            company.append(Html.fromHtml("<br>"));
            company.append("Approximate distance:   " + roDistance + " feet.");
```

---

**Error Thrown:** `The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) TextView, int`. Which makes sense, however I am used to working in PHP where I do this often.

---

Here is my layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/location_select"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_below="@id/row_2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row_4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_below="@id/row_3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/next_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Textview remains constant, then you can do this..

```
int[] companyIds = { R.id.company_id_1,
        R.id.company_id_2, R.id.company_id_3,...};
```

and in code do this

```
TextView company_select = (TextView)findViewById(companyIds[i]);
```

Comment: also, could add 'final static private' and

Comment: also get rid of length and just use companyIds.length to ensure loop follows actual set of ids

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure about this line,

```
TextView company_select = company_ + i;
```

??
That line  throws the error (Exception).

What's the meaning of that line, What you want to achieve?

Just store your textview's id in int array..

```
int[] textviewIds = { R.id.company_id_1,
        R.id.company_id_2, R.id.company_id_3,R.id.company_id_4,R.id.company_id_5...};
```

and use this array in your for loop,

```
TextView company_select = (TextView)findViewById(textviewIds[i]);
```

Comment: I need to fix my question, I'll do that in a second. I have `company_1` thru `company_5` as id's in xml, what I meant was, is there a way to increment the `_1` each pass of the `for` loop? Sorry about the question.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing is not possible.

You could use Reflection but that would be overkill.
Try the following

```
List<Integer> companies= Arrays.asList(R.id.company_1,R.id.company_2,R.id.company_3,R.id.company_4,R.id.company_5);
```

And get it with:

```
companies.get(i%5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Integer.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) 
Then the call will be `TextView company_select = company_ + Integer.toString(i);`